# Bundling Angular vendor to put them on a CDN

Tags: angular, angular-cli

The philosophy in my company is to create large numbers of “micro” application, all based on angular 2, to handle and separate each task currently done by 2 or 3 very large applications.

Considering that we currently have 2500 active users each day and around 30 applications for certain users, even if we compress the generated bundle, it will still make: 2500 * 30 * 300 so 22.5gb per day of bandwidth since the cache is cleaned each day.

If we could just put the vendor on the CDN, we would reduce this by the number of applications and we will get to only 750 mb (which is way better).

Is it possible to generate a bundle with the vendor only, and if yes, which vendor should I put in it? I supposed that I could put all these in the vendor: `@angular/common`, `@angular/compiler`, `@angular/core`, `@angular/forms`, `@angular/http`, `@angular/platform-browser`, `@angular/platform-browser-dynamic`, `@angular/router`, `core-js`, `ts-helpers`, `zone.js` since they are all my dependencies defined in package.json

From this list:

- How can I generate a bundle with these vendors?
- How can I tell webpack not to bundle them?
- Can I just put them in the head of my html?

Comment: I don't see that helping at all. Angular doesn't make separate requests for different dependencies; when you build and deploy the app it should bundle everything up (using Webpack in the case of `ng build`) into a handful of JS files. You could put those on an CDN, if you have access to an internal one, and just serve the index file.

Comment: In fact you can prove this to yourself - open your browser's network tab and visit one of those sites (if none are up yet, [here's one of mine](http://salary-stats-probative-agalwood.cfapps.pez.pivotal.io/)). You can see that it's not making specific requests for e.g. @angular/core.

Comment: It's bundled by webPack, as far as I understand, it does not take all the file but only the one we need, shouldn't it be problematic if we use one single bundle?

Comment: Now it's not clear what you're asking. I mean you could put each of your different applications' built JS files in a CDN, if the load on your server is proving to be a problem. My point is that your premise, putting a specific dependency on a CDN, is flawed due to the way your product is built.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Is it more clear now?

Comment: 1.
It is legitimate demand to use vendor bundle in CDN with all the API functions without tree-shaking. That same vendor bundle being loaded from CDN would be used for 25 projects. Yes, at the first http request the user would download very big vendor bundle but that same vendor bundle wouldn't be changed for the 25 projects and it would be cached in the user's borowser to the end of world. The 25 projects are very small comparing to the size of the vendor budnle and are frequently changed and released with changes demanded from users.

Comment: 2.
At present every time I use in one of the 25 projects some new function from the vendor bundle the vendor bundle is regenerated with tree-shaking and I end-up with 25 unique vendor bundles - it is very inefficient. Is it possible to have @angular angular on CDN with angular-cli ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I recommend to use the CDN for prod environment. That way you can offload your web server traffic from these javascript/css downloads and it will also increase page response for the end users if these cdns are geolocated. In the dev environments, use your local machine. Configure the startup/boot js file to determine where to get the js dependencies(dev,prod,etc)

Comment: This is for an intranet only, but I'm not sure about the content of the bundle

Comment: technically you can have it coded/configured so that if cdn is not available you can get it from your intranet web server. if response time becomes an issue and have cdn resource then one way to help is to put those js dependencies in cdn